How to select data from list using Query with UNIQUE function in google sheet?
(https://i.sstatic.net/owtnmoA4.png)
I have threes columns in list. I want to display all columns by using Query function to select unique data base on column Account Name or Account No with condition as below:

Display all data that have Transaction Type = 'Journal'
And display data that have Transaction Type = 'Adjustment' except Account Name or Account No has already in Transaction Type = 'Journal'.

Anybody, please help me.

Final query
Link to google sheet
=QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT A, B, C where C = 'Journal' or (C = 'Adjustment' and not D matches '" & JOIN("|", QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT D where C = 'Journal'")) & "')")

This does require that you create another Column with the formula =CONCATENATE(A3, B3).
For example, this would give Cash101 for the first row in your example.
Explanation
Let's divide the query into parts:

where C = 'Journal' - Select all those rows where Transaction Type = 'Journal'
C = 'Adjustment' and not D matches '" & JOIN("|", QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT D where C = 'Journal'")) & "'

C = 'Adjustment' - Select those rows where Transaction Type = 'Adjustment'
QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT D where C = 'Journal'") - Select all those values whose Account Name+Account No have Transaction Type = 'Journal'
JOIN("|", QUERY(A2:D, "SELECT D where C = 'Journal'")) - Merge all the values obtained in step 2 into single string separated by '|'. (The result would look like 'Cash101|Office supplies104|Prepaid rent106')
C = 'Adjustment' and not D matches ... - Select only those rows that have Transaction Type = 'Adjustment' whose Account Name+Account No are not present in rows that have Transaction Type = 'Journal'



